# mod_wsgi for multiple trac projects [Windows]

Tags: trac, mod-wsgi, multiple-instances

I have a system with **windows server 2008**, Apache **httpd 2.2** and **trac 0.11** i'm using **mod_wsgi** so the apache server do the web server job.

[Integration with Trac](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac) after read this site i found that the most suitable solution was 
the following (i have in my httpd.conf the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-trac.conf`)

**httpd-trac.conf**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIDaemonProcess tracs processes=3 threads=25 maximum-requests=1000

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/trac/([^/]+)
RewriteCond c:\Project\Services\Trac\%1\conf\trac.ini !-f
RewriteRule . - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/trac/([^/]+)
RewriteRule . - [E=trac.env_path:c:\Project\Services\Trac\%1]

WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/trac/([^/]+) c:\Project\Trac\trac.wsgi

<Directory c:\Project\Trac>
    WSGIProcessGroup tracs
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

the problem i encouter is the following:

> C:\Project\Apache\bin>httpd.exe -k start
>   Syntax error on line 3 of C:/Project/Apache/conf/extra/httpd-trac.conf:
>   Invalid command 'WSGIDaemonProcess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a 
>   module not included in the server configuration

**The objective:**

My objective is to have multiple trac projects with diferente authentication information.
If you have other solution than this please tell me =)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't support daemon mode of mod_wsgi. Just try removing WSGIDaemonProcess/WSGIProcessGroup directives. This will result in all Trac instances running in same process. Most of the time doing that should be fine.